# Julia - Identity matrix - eye() alternative

Tags: julia

I'm working with what I guess is an older textbook that is using an older version of Julia as they are using the eye() function to create an identity matrix, which appears to not exist in the version I am currently using. What alternative is there for eye()?

[image]
Is there a